# actuator - readiness always return 503

Tags: spring-boot-actuator

I have a Spring Boot and added actuator for health check .
in my pom i have :

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.7.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

in my application properties I have :

```
management.endpoint.health.enabled=true
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=env,auditevents,beans,caches,configprops,health,httptrace,info,httptrace,metrics,mappings,scheduledtasks
management.endpoints.health.sensitive=false
management.health.db.enabled=false
management.health.defaults.enabled=true
xmanagement.endpoint.health.show-details=always
management.endpoint.health.show-components=always
management.health.probes.enabled=true
```

I added the probes.enabled=true for liveness and readiness  so I can add it to YAML file for Kubernetes

in my Application i have :

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAAF
@EnableCaching
@EnableEncryptableProperties
@EnableScheduling
@EnableOcpKafka
@EnableCsmsApi
@EnableConfigurationProperties({KafkaHealthCheckProperties.class})
@Import({DbServiceValidator.class, /*StorageServiceValidator.class,*/ KafkaServiceValidator.class})
```

the imports are for implementation for health for storage, DB, and Kafka

when I call actuator/health I get the following :   ** I always get status: OUT_OF_SERVICE ** from readiness.....  I always get 503 because my readiness is out of service .....

```
status  "OUT_OF_SERVICE"
components  
com.att.ocp.health.services.db.DbServiceValidator   
status  "UP"
com.att.ocp.health.services.kafka.KafkaServiceValidator 
status  "UP"
diskSpace   
status  "UP"
livenessState   
status  "UP"
ping    
status  "UP"
readinessState  
status  "OUT_OF_SERVICE"
groups  
0   "liveness"
1   "readiness"
```

can someone help me figure out what is wrong? it seems my application is not fully ready but I know it's up and running as expected, can I override this status and for readiness always return "UP"   ???

Comment: Are you able to share a small sample that can be run to reproduce this?

Comment: Hello i have the same issue. Can you share if you have any long running CommandLineRunners or stuff on ApplicationReadyEvent? This seems to be an issue for me. After they complete the readinessState is UP

Comment: peter you are correct ,  i have some cache that didnt finish , that's why i have always get down...